# How can i set multiple words as a single command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to set a command that has multiple words (for example a 'how old are you' command) in python but I am not sure how. My code looks like this:

```
@client.command(aliases=['how old are you'])
async def age(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I am 30')
```

I tried the aliases thing but obviously I am missing something

Comment: I do not think that is possible, a better approach is to use the first word as the commad and using `ctx.message.content == "how old are you"` and using a conditional to then send the response

Comment: That is not possible. You can only have something like `async def how_old_are_you`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend you to just use an if statement such as:

```
@client.command()
async def age(ctx):
   if ctx.message.content == "how old are you":
      ctx.send("I am 30")
```

That is a very simple way to do it, and it should work totally fine. Otherwise I will recommend you to search on google, or check youtube out. There is a lot of usefull content :D

Answer (score 1):

If you have certain and few commands, use optional arguments;

```
async def how(ctx, *args):
    items = ['old', 'are', 'you']
    
    if items == args:
         await ctx.send('I am 30.')

    # Or add some fuzzy logic and combine the strings. 
    # items = [ ['old', 'is'], ['are', 'it'], ['going', 'you']]
    # how is it going and how old are you
```

If you want to develop a complete bot, I guess it requires a little bit natural language processing, but I believe you can achieve your request as below. For NLP `spacy` could be an option.

It's a conceptual thought, I hope it would be helpful.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')


def nlp_spacy(arg):
    doc = nlp(' '.join(arg))
    # Below line gives you the object. F.e; age, you..
    return [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubj")]
    

@bot.command()
async def how(ctx, *args):
    objs= nlp_spacy(args)
    if 'old' in objs:
        await ctx.send('I'm 30')
```

Comment: Wow that is a very interesting way to do it. I will definetly look more into it and use it but for other commands. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it what you wrote but it displays this error when I try to run the command: "Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got tuple)". What should I do?

Comment: @AlexVenova I missed the `*` before the arg. The correct version is `def nlp_spacy(*arg)` The nlp_spacy expects the string in wrong version, but I had passed the tuple :) I'll correct also original comment now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It stills doesn't work. It displays the same error. Maybe am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexVenova nlp expects string, but arg is list. I fixed the code by adding `join`. Can you try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made a mistake... Here's the corrected code, and I'm very sorry for "not telling the truth".

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
     if ctx.message.content == "how old are you":
        ctx.send("I am 30")
        return
```

Comment: Nevermind, I just tested it and it displays the error "Command "how" is not found". I think I'd have to use async def how(ctx): instead of on_message. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ehm. You do know that when it's a @client.event it's not a real command. It's more like a listener. It checks if the certain thing happens, in this particular we use a on_message to check if our message contains the wordsame we are looking for. If you changed it to how, it wouldn't be anice event anymore.  That would completely destroyed your code...